# Issue "Could not fetch/save url https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo"

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I am trying to set up the Docker repository on CentOS, after I run the command

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

I am getting error message:

> Could not fetch/save url
>   https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo to file
>   /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo: [Errno 12] Timeout on
>   https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo: (28,
>   'Operation timed out after 30005 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes
>   received')

I am following the docker documentation to set up the repository.

Step 1: Install required packages. yum-utils provides the yum-config-manager utility, and device-mapper-persistent-data and lvm2 are required by the devicemapper storage driver.

```
$ sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
```

Step 2: Use the following command to set up the stable repository.

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

**Expected result**: System should download the files.

**Actual result**: Not able to download the files.

Comment: I think that from your server you do not have access to the URL: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo What is the output of the following commands?
```dig download.docker.com A +short
ping IP-RESULT from dig command.
curl https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem but I solved it by updating the yum config file, just add `timeout=120` to `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release

#add timeout here
timeout=120
```

Set `timeout` to 2 min (or 3 min = 180), restart the server then re-run your command.

**NOTE:** you need to edit the `yum.conf` file as a **super user** in order to be able to save your changes.

- To switch to **super user** run next:

```
sudo -i
```

- To edit your file and save the changes use the `nano` editor (or Vi).

I think that it is not necessarily a good solution but it worked well for me.

Should help!

Comment: This actually worked. I was getting this error:

`Could not fetch/save url https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo to file /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo: (28, 'timed out before SSL handshake')`

The operating system here was NethServer 7, which is CentOS-based .

Answer (score 2):

By adding this to my /etc/yum.conf file

## add timeout here

timeout=300.

It fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I followed instruction in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568590/506588 to set

```
ip_resolve=4
```

in /etc/yum.conf [main] section then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you face any error while trying to create a stable docker repo, You may use the following command.

**Command:**

```
curl --silent -SL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothings works, then just do

`wget https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo ; mv docker-ce.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/.`

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo to download the file manual then upload it to /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

Answer (score 0):

its just because ipv6 is still not completely deployed due to which we get timeouts or slow response.
just disable your system's/VM's ipv6 and it will work fine.

to disable the IPv6 use following commands (run as root or use sudo):

```
echo -e 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 \nnet.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1' > /etc/sysctl.d/disable_ipv6.conf

sysctl -p

systemctl restart systemd-sysctl.service
```

then run

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

check repositories:

```
yum repolist
```

install docker:

```
yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```